# UIMA Ruta with Maven

Tags: java, maven, uima, ruta

I am beginner in UIMA Ruta. I followed [this](https://github.com/apatry/ruta-with-maven) to use Ruta with Maven. I understood this but I want to do few more things.

**Below is my simple test case to run this example**

```
/**
* Test Annotators on default input to ascertain their proper functioning.
* 
*/

public class TestAnnotator {

/**
 * UIMA type holding dates.
 */
public static final String DATE_TYPE = "uima.ruta.example.TestAnnotator.DateValue";

/**
 * UIMA type holding Eight Digit Numbers.
 */
public static final String EIGHT_DIGIT_TYPE = "uima.ruta.example.TestAnnotator.EightDigit";

/**
 * UIMA type holding Number block.
 */
public static final String NUMBER_VALUE_BLOCK = "uima.ruta.example.TestAnnotator.NumberValueBlock";

/**
 * 
 */
public static final String NUM = "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.NUM";
/**
 * Text to process.
 */
public static final String TEXT = "I will be out of office from September 2nd, 2013 to September 20th, 2013.\n"
        + "Dates like 9/2/2013 and 9/20/13 are also recognized. Eight Digit Number 99192293 and Nine digit Number <Span> 113993910"
        + " <Value> 900839806 </Value> <Coordinates> <x0> 916 </x0> <y0> 268 </y0> <x1> 1069 </x1> <y1> 290 </y1> </Coordinates> <OcrConfidence /></Span>";

/**
 * Engine instance used for UIMA analysis
 */
private AnalysisEngine engine;

/**
 * CAS instance used for analysis
 */
private CAS cas;

/**
 * Sets Annotator Engine
 * 
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Starting Analysis Engine");
    engine = AnalysisEngineFactory
            .createEngine("com.demo.extraction.uima.annotators.TestAnnotatorEngine");
    cas = engine.newCAS();
    cas.setDocumentText(TEXT);
    engine.process(cas);
}

/**
 * Tests the input
 * 
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Extracting date from");
    System.out.println(TEXT);
    for (AnnotationFS date : CasUtil.select(cas, cas.getTypeSystem()
            .getType(DATE_TYPE))) {
        System.out.println("Found: " + date.getCoveredText());
    }

    System.out.println("Extracting Number Block from");
    System.out.println(TEXT);
    for (AnnotationFS number : CasUtil.select(cas, cas.getTypeSystem()
            .getType(NUM))) {
        System.out.println("Found: " + number.getCoveredText());
    }
}
}
```

**This is my script mentioned below.**

```
DECLARE DateValue, DateRange, DayValue, MonthValue, YearValue, DateValueBlock;
// Number Related Types

// A date is a month, followed by a day, optionally an ordinal suffix and a year//
//examples : "january 1st 2008", "february 28, 2010"
W{REGEXP("(?i)
         (january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)"
    ) -> MARK(MonthValue)} 
  NUM{-> MARK(DayValue)} 
   W?{REGEXP("(?i)(th|st|nd|rd)")} 
   COMMA? 
   NUM{-> MARK(YearValue), MARK(DateValue, 1, 5)};
// A date can also be specified in the MM/DD/YYYY format
NUM{-> MARK(MonthValue)} "/" NUM{-> MARK(DayValue)} "/" NUM{-> MARK(YearValue),       MARK(DateValue, 1, 
     5)};// A date range
 "from" DateValue "to" DateValue{-> MARK(DateRange, 1, 4)};
```

As suggested in the tutorial. I made this script using a different UIMA Ruta project(Call it Example Project) in the same eclipse workspace. I executed it as UIMA ruta file and got the corresponding descriptor file(TestAnnotator.xml). I pasted the same with just altering following to

```
<imports><import name="org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.BasicTypeSystem"/></imports>
```

which was initially pointing to BasicTypeSystem.xml file.Currently I am able to build it and execute this script but the descriptor file generated(TestAnnotator.xml) uses local file path in the respective xml. These local file paths are those with folders in previous UIMA project(Example Project).

When I tried to configure run settings for script file at above mentioned path, i.e. in my Maven project the configuration was not able to locate script at the given path.

**How should I add dynamic nature of Ruta script within a Maven Project**?

Please help.

Comment: Please describe your problem more accurate and in particular don't expect here to get working examples from others. Please describe what you've already tried and what does not work with error message outputs etc.

Comment: Since UIMA Ruta 2.2.0, the absolute paths in the descriptor are optional. The analysis engine tries now to locate them additionally in the classpath of the application. I assume that maybe a folder of the script project needs to be added to the classpath of your application.

Example: the analysis engine descriptor in the example "Ruta with Maven" specifies no absolute paths. The configuration parameter for the main script points to the script file with the complete namespace in the resource folder.

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: @Peter I converted my project to UIMA Ruta by the option provided by convert project to UIMA Ruta. It generated the folders you are talking about. I added my script to the folder but now it is giving Exception in thread "main" org.apache.uima.util.InvalidXMLException .  I also want to does any maven plugin provide support to execute script file while building ?

Comment: Can you add the complete exception? I haven't tried to run an analysis engine during maven build, but that should be possible with something like mvn exec (http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html) and RutaLauncher (https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/uima/ruta/trunk/ruta-ep-ide-ui/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/ruta/ide/launching/RutaLauncher.java)

Comment: @Peter plese find complete exception
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.uima.util.InvalidXMLException: Invalid descriptor at file:/D:/extractor/.
 at org.apache.uima.util.impl.XMLParser_impl.parse(XMLParser_impl.java:196)
 at org.apache.uima.util.impl.XMLParser_impl.parseResourceSpecifier(XMLParser_impl.java:376)
 at org.apache.uima.util.impl.XMLParser_impl.parseResourceSpecifier(XMLParser_impl.java:357)
 at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.Ruta.wrapAnalysisEngine(Ruta.java:97)
 at org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher.main(RutaLauncher.java:119)

Comment: Also ..... 
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/extractor/; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1236)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
 at org.apache.uima.util.impl.XMLParser_impl.parse(XMLParser_impl.java:179)

but the path "file:/D:/extractor/" is not where the code is placed on local file system. I have been trying to change to appropriate path but with no success.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52587/discussion-between-anshul-and-peter-kluegl)